# using arulesSequences package : Error in makebin(data, file) : 'sid' invalid

Tags: r, arules

I am using `arulesSequences` package in R. The documentation is too little for the type of data that `read_baskets` function receives. I guess data should be in text (.txt) format. Column names are: "sequenceID", "eventID", "SIZE" and "items". My data has about 200,000 rows and looks like following in z.txt file:

```
1,1364,3,{12,17,19}
1,1130,4,{14,17,21,23}
1,1173,3,{19,23,9}
1,98,5,{14,15,2,21,5}
2,1878,4,{1,10,14,3}
2,1878,13,{1,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,21,24,25,5}
2,1878,1,{2}
```

I tried to  use:

```
x <- read_baskets("z.txt", sep = ",",info =c("sequenceID","eventID","SIZE"))
s <- cspade(x,parameter = list(support = 0.001),control = list(verbose = 
TRUE),tmpdir = tempdir())
```

but I get this error :

> Error in makebin(data, file) : 'sid' invalid

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example. When I run your code on the snippet you have provided, I do not get an error. (well done for your example so far though, it's good except that it doesn't reproduce your error!)

Comment: as stands though, it appears that one of your sequence IDs is not "valid", whatever that means. Maybe that helps you debug your problem. Do sequence IDs need to be unique, or numbers, or something like that?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee thanks for your answer. I found the problem. I'll post it

Answer (score 1):

The combination of sequenceID and eventID must be unique.

Otherwise you'll get one of these errors:

- Error in makebin(data, file) : 'sid' invalid
- Error in makebin(data, file) : 'eid' invalid

This implies further that the items in your .txt file (per sequenceID, eventID combination) must be in the same row and (possibly) be separated with the same separator as the rest of the .txt file. Therefore, the item column should be the last column.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, and I'm posting it in case that some one has the same problem. The problem is both SequenceID and eventID (first and second columns must be ordered blockwise. package mentions this point, but I only ordered the first column.

Comment: what does it mean "ordered blockwise" ? Please explain, I am using this package and new to it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I tried the following code:    
data@itemsetInfo <- arrange(data@itemsetInfo, sequenceID, eventID)

But it still did not work.

Comment: @Ghazal, I'm in the same error, but since you came with the solution. What does it mean "ordered blockwise"? How do we do that? Thanks.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatheus The package documentation mentions that "The transactions must be ordered by sequenceID and eventID" simultaneously. Order all transactions based on sequenceID first, then for all transactions with the same sequenceID order them based on eventID.

Comment: So, i have a transnational class data which is not ordered according to Eid. hence the  Error in makebin(data, file) : 'eid' invalid. how do i order it?